# Glimpse Configuration - ambiguous resource

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, web-config, glimpse

I try to get running Glimpse in my MVC4 website but i am getting error:

```
Ambiguous resource with name 'glimpse_config' found.
```

when i run /Glimpse.axd.

I configured it as the documention says. I also tried to remove and reinstall it without success.
I turned logging on and it says:

```
2013-04-08 10:42:08.5762 | WARN | Multiple Resources with name of 'glimpse_ajax'. Resources should have unique names. | 
2013-04-08 10:42:08.5762 | WARN | Multiple Resources with name of 'glimpse_client'. Resources should have unique names. | 
2013-04-08 10:42:08.5762 | WARN | Multiple Resources with name of 'glimpse_config'. Resources should have unique names. | 
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue after upgrading to glimpse 1.3, the solution that worked for me was to clear the temporary ASP.NET files, which are most likely here:

> %TEMP%\Temporary ASP.NET Files

or here:

> %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files

It looks like you've also asked this through the glimpse issues, where I've also posted [my answer](https://github.com/Glimpse/Glimpse/issues/297#issuecomment-16844553).

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have multiple copies of the DLL in your bin directory. (Somehow?)

Clean your build and retry.

Comment: i did this with no success. i have the dlls in the packages directory and in \bin like every other library

Comment: on server i can call glimpse.axd and turn it on but no glimpse icon appears

Comment: Was Glimpse.axd broken before and now it is working? I'm having trouble following along with you.

Comment: on localhost nothing works. on azure i can call /Glimpse.axd to turn it on but nothing more works.

Comment: Reach out to me on Twitter and I'll give you more support. I've got the same username there as I do here.