# Resource with name 'glimpse_config' could not be found

Tags: glimpse

I had a Glimpse install working fine, and then updated from 1.2 to 1.3, and now when I go to glimpse.axd, I see "Resource with name 'glimpse_config' could not be found."

This is an ASP.NET 4.5 site (DotNetNuke 7.0.5), with Glimpse.Core 1.3 and Glimpse.AspNet 1.2.1 (previously, it has Glimpse.Core 1.2, Glimpse.AspNet 1.2, and Glimpse.Ado 1.2), running on IIS 8.

Any ideas about what I should be investigating to see where the error is coming from?

Answer (score 1):

I think I figured it out.  I had a custom security policy that required me to be logged in.  When the security policy turned Glimpse off, it looks like that's the response that I get.

Comment: +1 Sometimes it helps to explain the problem to someone else, and then you get it ;p

Comment: That still either sounds a little buggy, or like we could have a better error message there. Would you mind sharing your policy?

Comment: Looks like that wasn't the entirety of it; when I logged in to remove the extension, I saw the Glimpse icon (right after I clicked to uninstall).  But, after reinstalling, I can get to glimpse.axd while logged out.

Comment: @nikmd23 The policy is at https://github.com/bdukes/DotNetNuke.Extensions.Glimpse/blob/master/Builds/net4.5/GlimpseSecurityPolicy.cs

Comment: A couple of us have had similar issues, this solution worked for us http://stackoverflow.com/a/16164213/495964